# js: return both a first-class object and a string from a variable

Tags: javascript, function, simplify, first-class

I've built a plugin that will use modules. Basically functions that can be added to the code in order to provide additional functionality.

In the plugin is a function to call these modules. Previously, I had called them like this:

```
processInstance($(doc).find('[data-bcp-crumbs]'), crumbs);
processInstance($(doc).find('[data-bcp-copyright]'), copyright);
processInstance($(doc).find('[data-bcp-activenav]'), activeNav);
```

The last part of each line is the name of a function that will be called within the processInstance script. So, I have the name of the function as both a string and a first-class object on each line. I would like to simplify that to something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i>module.length;i++) {
    processInstance($(doc).find('[data-bcp-'+module[i].toLowerCase()+']'), window[module[i]]);
}
```

The module array is added to after each instance of the actual module code. I'm doing that like this:

```
module.push('crumbs');
```

This doesn't work because window[module[i]] is returning undefined.

How does my code need to be modified to make this work?

Here is an jsfiddle example of the entire plugin with a simple module inserted: http://jsfiddle.net/michaeljimmy/U8anp/1/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I added the actual question to my question? :)

Comment: Please post ALL the relevant code!

Comment: Can you setup an example in JS fiddle.  I'll take a look at it.  Just a guess though the window object does not have your module[i] property at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine helped me find the answer to this question. First, though, I noticed an error in the for loop. I had > instead of <. That didn't help. :)

The concept with the code was correct. The issue was scope. If you look at the jsfiddle, you'll see that the whole thing is in an enclosure, including the functions I was trying to call. So, there was no way window had access to the functions. We ended up making a couple simple changes.

First, along with module.push('crumbs'), or whatever the function name is, we added:

```
functions.crumbs = crumbs;
```

Then instead of using window[module[i]], we used

```
functions[module[i]]
```

Without the enclosure, window[module[i]] would have worked just fine.